# iOS Strong vs Weak UI programmatically creation

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I used storyboard and when I accessed an UI element I created a property and linked it. This property is weak. To my understanding the property can be weak since it is already added to the view and the views retains it.

In an other project I do not use storyboard. Now I am not sure how to define a UI element. I think this can be done both, situation 1:

```
@interface LoginView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *login
@end

- (instancetype) init {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        _login = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self addSubview:_login];
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Situation 2:

```
 @interface LoginView
 @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *login //<<notice weak
 @end

 - (instancetype) init {
    if (self == [super init]) {

        UIButton login = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [self addSubview:login];
        _login = login

        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
    return self;
 }
```

My question is: "Can both situation be used? If so is there a preferred way?"

Own ideas: I think situation two is preferred since it doesn't create a second strong pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work fine.

Personally I prefer strong, so that I'm not relying on another view retaining something.

Also strong has slightly less overhead as opposed to a weak reference which needs to be tracked and zeroed to nil automatically (not that you would notice this time difference).

Answer (score 1):

You can still use weak reference because the views super view will be having strong reference to it.